# Unable to POST data in axios (React to SpringBoot) Formatted question in screenshot attached

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

In React component :
    I am setting

```
const object = {
          name: this.state.Name,
          place: this.state.Place
    }
    callBackend(object).then(validateResult => {
          if (validateResult.valid === true) {
            this.setState({status: 'saved'});
        } else {
            this.setState({status: 'error'});
        }
    }
--------------
// this call goes to service
import axiosInstance from "../Axios";
export const callBackend = (object) => 
    axiosInstance.post(`/employee/saveInfo`, { object }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    return res.data;
});
----------------
In java:
@PostMapping(path = "/saveInfo")
    public ResponseEntity<List<object>> saveInfo(@RequestBody Object o) {
       System.out.println(o.getName);// getting java.lang.NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: Please Write Code in ``` ```  so that it can be auto formatted in question.

Comment: When you inspect element and check network tab is the data going properly ?

Comment: requestPayload is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is no brackets around object.
export const callBackend = (object) => 
    axiosInstance.post(`/employee/saveInfo`, object).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    return res.data;